# Angular : Unable to parse Nested Json

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I have the following JSON response from a web service. I want to use it on the front end but the "codeSubstance" is not showing anything. How do I parse it correctly ?

I've tried the following :

```
<tr *ngFor ="let m of medicamentsDetailslist;">
  <td>{{m.compositions.substancesActives.codeSubstance}}</td>
</tr>
```

and this also

```
 <tr *ngFor ="let m of medicamentsDetailslist;">
      <td>{{m.compositions.substancesActives["codeSubstance"]}}</td>
    </tr>
```

[image: Jsonparse]

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compositions` and `substancesActives` are again an array, so you should be iterating over it again

```
<tr *ngFor ="let m of medicamentsDetailslist;">
     <td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let comp of m.compositions">
           <ng-container *ngFor="let sub of comp.substancesActives">
              {{sub.codeSubstance}}
           </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I have tried your code but it is still blank. The data is here. Console.log shows it. Where can be the issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I see that 'compositions' is also an array.. You will need another iteration over ther

Comment: Thanks again. Indians smart people :)

Comment: I recommend to have a strong type structure, after getting assigned your json to an object on you Observable , you could do simply only one ngFor against the right structure, ngFor is expensive for large amount of data

Answer (score 1):

hi i think you have an array in substancesActives, so try this :

```
<tr *ngFor ="let m of medicamentsDetailslist;">
  <td>{{m.compositions.substancesActives[0].codeSubstance}}</td>
</tr>
```

If it's ok, so add a new loop for substanceActives

> EDIT (more details in comments) :
>
> m.compositions[0].substancesActives[0].codeSubstance

Comment: Tried it too but got that :  Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Hum... And the code of Amit Chigadani doesn't work too ? And are you sure, codeSubstance can't be null ?

Comment: Here it is the good one but it was near :   <td>{{m.compositions[0].substancesActives[0].codeSubstance}}</td>

Comment: Yes, i ve just see the problem ! Nice ;)